# Multithreading Java- Threads clashing/overwriting issue

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, arraylist, threadpool

I am using a simple thread pool to read in a large dictionary I have written a for loop that loops through the whole dictionary (10000 words), I have tried to get it so it stores every 500 into a thread assigning that sub arraylist to a single thread to handle.

When there are 500 words within the arraylist it then stores it within an instance of a class 'Words'. This simply stores and allows access to an arrayList (the arrayList assigned to that thread).

This doesnt appear to be working as there are duplicates and most the time the last 500 words in the dictionary are what all the threads end up using which I find strange. In addition I also noticed when I add in a simple timeout for 3 seconds at the end of the inside of that for loop shown below it works however this seems like a horrible fix and I want this program to be as efficent and fast as possible.

```
// Executor Program
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
    ArrayList<String> words123 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); i++) {
        words123.add(dictionary.get(i));
        if(words123.size() == 1000) {
            Words wordsList = new Words(words123);
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(wordsList, passwords, stp);
            executor.execute(worker);
            words123 = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    //wait for all jobs to complete
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }
    System.out.println("Finished all threads");




// WORD OBJECT ------------------
public class Words {
public static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

public Words(ArrayList words) {
    this.words = words;
}

public int getSize() {
    return words.size();
}

public String getWord(int i) {
    return words.get(i);
}
```

}

```
//WORKER THREAD ----------------

    public static Words wordList;
public static int cmd;
public static HashMap<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
public static SimpleThreadPool stp;
/**
 * Constructor
 * @param s
 */
public WorkerThread(Words word, HashMap passwords, SimpleThreadPool stp, int cmd){
    this.wordList = word;
    //System.out.println("in  " + words);
    //Read in hashes using readFromFile method
    this.passwords = passwords;
    this.stp = stp;
    this.cmd = cmd;
}

/**
 * For a thread pool to function, ensure that the run() method terminates
 * This method prints out the command, calls a function, then prints end and terminates
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start.");
    //System.out.println("WOOOO  " + wordList.getWords() + cmd);

    for(int i = 0; i < wordList.getSize(); i++){
        Password pass = new Password(wordList.getWord(i), hashPassword(wordList.getWord(i)));
        //System.out.println(pass.getOriginalPass());
        //checkHash(pass);

        // Check password with letter-number edits (e.g. a-->@)
        letterSymbolEdit(pass);

        // Check password with capital letter edits
        //capitalsEdit(pass);

        // Reverse password
        reverseEdit(pass);

        // Concatenate all words in dictionary
        //concatEdit(pass);

        printPermutations(pass);

        // All possible numbers generated and appended to string
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            numberBuilder("", 0, j, pass);
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End.");
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you use a Vector in place of arrayList. I believe Vectors can be used for Synchronised operations.

Comment: Please show us your `Words` and `WorkerThread` classes at least

Comment: @may could this really be the issue? in terms of I pass an arraylist to a new instance of a class how would them instances override.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the 'words' variable in the Words class is static, that means that every instance of that class is using the same list.

Also, since you're trying to get efficient, I would use a different approach. Instead of

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
```

use

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(cores, cores, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, workQueue);
executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();
```

and then add Runnable instances directly to the workQueue. In this way you don't have to wait to divide words among threads yourself: threads will fetch them as soon as they complete a task.

Comment: Thanks so much! Very amateur mistake made, been working on this for hours thanks! :)

Comment: Ahh thanks, it needs to be as quick as possible so I removed that Words class I implemented in the example from my question and now just pass over the arrayList as appose to sending across an instance to a class containing the arraylist for that thread, would you say this is more efficent too? Also thanks for the suggestion just trying it now :)

Comment: Since you already have a thread pool that it's entitled to distribute the work among its threads, there is no need to build sublists of words: you can implement each Runnable to only process one word. Also, I've just noticed, what happen if your dictionary.size() is not a multiple of 1000?